# electric diagrams applications

Tags: architecture

I'm currently want to install an application to draw  electric diagrams but I do not succeed. I want to know if these applications exist for ubuntu, and if so, how to do to install?

Comment: There are some.  Just look through science/engineering part of Ubuntu software center.  There's some for circuit analysis and some for pcb design. Alternatively you could use WINE

Answer (score 0):

If they are simple enough you can install "Dia" a diagram editor.

```
sudo apt-get install dia
```

At least for me was great in simple stuff.